# Api Request with Bearer Token in Angular

Tags: angular, api, oauth, jwt, token

The case is to build a Login and Register page in Angular and access an api when registered and logged in.
I know the concept of sending the login data to an, api getting the token back etc.

My Problem is that I don't know how to implement the workflow in Angular. The backend is written in PHP. I'm searching for a concept.

What is the best way and do I need Routeguards, Interceptor, Lokalstorage, Cookies?

To access an secure api and also being able to see api results in e.g postman with a token is my target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you need is `interceptor` - it let you "intercept" all HTTP request and edit them.
for example you can do this:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
  Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  const authToken = localstorage.getItem('token');
  const authReq = req.clone({
  headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + authToken)
 });
return next.handle(authReq);
}
}
```

then you need to add it to your providers array:

```
{
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: AuthInterceptor,
  multi: true
}
```

to exclude `/login` route - you can wrap the interceptor code with `if` condition:

```
if( !req.url.startsWith('/login') { }
```

or you can provide this `interceptor` only in the other modules and not in login module (if you have any)

good luck :)

Comment: that's an excellent idea for a set token but when you call public API, the token is assigned to a header. for example : login api

Comment: Is it possible to use interceptor with header instead of local storage?

Comment: what do you mean? it's usually stored in localStorage so we need to take it from there and add it to the header of the outgoing request ( as I did )

Comment: The header is set in php. I'm searching for a get request to access the api.

Answer (score 0):

I created a service for API and I use it to call the API.
if you have a refresh token, you can develop this function.

```
post<T>(url: string, payload: T, needAuth: boolean = false): any {

   if (needAuth) {
     this.httpOptions.headers = this.httpOptions.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.tokenService.getAccessToken());
   }

   return this.httpClient.post<T>((this.serverURL) + url, payload, this.httpOptions)
   .pipe(
      map((res: any) => {
      return res.body;
      })
   );
}
```